# Decimal to binary converter c++

Tags: c++

I'm creating this program just for fun but i'm havin a problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int j = 1;
std::vector<int> n_bin(j);
int n=0; 
int a;
cin>>n;
do
{

    n_bin[j] = n%2;
    n= n/2;
    a++;
    j++;

}while(n>0);

for(j=a; j>0; j--)
{

    cout<<n_bin[j];
}

return 0;
```

}
the only problem is the output, infact before the real binary number i get a lot of more number for example:
if i assign 104 to n i get: 246978862916874543020108190880108137760108190884026797651687454302000108137760108191524026797651687454302183600828414839627280108137760146978862716874543020001321208800108136960-10108137760108364961101000 where only the last 7 are useful.

Comment: your `vector` holds only `1` element, but you try to access it out of bounds in `n_bin[j]`. That's undefined behaviour

Comment: `a` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n_bin` is initialized to have exactly one element, at `n_bin[0]`. `n_bin[j]` exhibits undefined behavior for any value of `j` other than 0, by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: how can i set my vector to hold more than 1 element?

Comment: vector::resize() or just use push_back and you don't need `j` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
void decToBinary(int n) 
{
    int binaryNum[1000];
    int i = 0;
    while(n > 0) 
    {
        binaryNum[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        i++;
    }
    for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        cout << binaryNum[j];
    }
}
```